# IExplorer automation mouse over

Tags: internet-explorer-10, browser-automation

By doing IExplorer 10 automation from C# I need to move the mouse over a given html element, or to fire the mouseover event on that element. I've tried this:

- Move the mouse, but even I can get the IE's Window Coordinates, I cannot get the real html element coordinates as always get the top-left window corner. Don't know how to calculate the real element on-screen coordinates to move the mouse over it.
- Don't know how to programmatically trigger the onmouseover event.

### Appreciate any ideas. Thank you.

What I really need is to display a menu that is handled by CSS hover.

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke JavaScript in the browser which will trigger the mouse over event.
To do that you need to follow the following steps:

1. Use `ShellWindowsClass` to enumerate `IWebBrowser2` tabs in order to find the tab you wand to inject to.
2. Get the `HTMLDocumentClass` of from the `Document` property of your tab from step 1.
3. Get the `IHTMLWindow2` parentWindow from the `Document` property above.
4. Use the `executeScript` method on the window object above to execute the JavaScript to trigger the mouse over event. Keep in mind, the `executeScript` method does not return any valid value. If you need to get a returned value back, that is a bit more involved.